# Simulate a click event to rotate divs as visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to simplify my front page for users by rotating articles.
I have used the basic ideas from [Learncode Academy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nWrIBB_bMA&list=PLoYCgNOIyGACnrXwo5HMCfOH9VT05znGv&index=12) to build a static menu/choice of article but what I really want to be able to do is to cycle through the articles, essentially by simulating a key press (i.e., the next button) say every 5000 mS.  The main javascript is `$(function(){

```
        $('.tab-boxes .tabs li').on('click', hidePanel);
        var boxToShow;

        function hidePanel () {
            var $box = $(this).closest('.tab-boxes');
            $box.find('.tabs li.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var boxToShow = $(this).attr('rel'); 
            $box.find('.box.active').fadeOut(300, showNextPanel);

        function showNextPanel(){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $("#"+boxToShow).fadeIn(300, function(){
                $(this).addClass('active');
                });   
            }
        }; 

        function changePanel () {
            var nextPanel = $box.next(); 
            hidePanel (nextbox);
        }    
    });`
```

So specifically, if no key press happens, I want to pick up the current active panel and trigger the next (or the first if it is the last). I have tried various fade ins

```
function transitionBox(from, to) {
    function next() {
        var nextTo;
        if (to.is(":last-child")) {
            nextTo = to.closest(".tab-boxes").children("div").first();
        } else {
            nextTo = to.next();
        }
        to.fadeIn(500, function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                transitionBox(to, nextTo);
            }, 3000);
        });
    }
```

but I just can't get it to work - anyone got any good ideas to help me?

Comment: can its possible for you to setup a fiddle for it?

Comment: I have added a fiddle as http://jsfiddle.net/Mishutka/p511safe/4/ - Some of it works.  The content boxes rotate. the panel tabs select, and show they are selected, but pressing the panel tabs does not take you to the correct box, and the mouse in and mouse out do not stop and restart the cycling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried analyzing your code and tried making it work but I am unable to do that.

So I have written entirely new code for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/p511safe/10/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".tabs li").click(function(){
        clearInterval(myInterval);
        openTab($(this));
        loopThroughTabs();
    });

    function openTab(tabLiObject)
    {
        if(!$(tabLiObject).hasClass("active"))
        {
            var oldSelectedLi = $(".tabs li.active");
            var oldPanelDivId = oldSelectedLi.attr("rel");
            oldSelectedLi.removeClass("active");
            $("#"+oldPanelDivId).removeClass("active").hide();

            $(tabLiObject).addClass("active");
            var newPanelDivId = $(tabLiObject).attr("rel");
            $("#"+newPanelDivId).removeClass("active");
            $("#"+newPanelDivId).fadeIn(500);
        }

    }
    var myInterval = null;

    function goToTab(fromFirst)
    {
        var currentLIIndex = $(".tabs li.active").index();
        var nextTabIndex = currentLIIndex+1;
        if(nextTabIndex > 3)
        {
            openTab($(".tabs li").first());
        }
        else
        {
            openTab($(".tabs li:eq("+nextTabIndex+" )" ));
        }

    }
    goToTab();

    function loopThroughTabs(){
        myInterval = setInterval(function(){
            goToTab();
        },2000);
    }
    loopThroughTabs();
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi - that is very helpful - I will now try to see if I can make the cursor in/cursor out pause the rotation

Comment: Brilliant - Thanks. I have added a couple of extra features - allowing the old panel to fade out, then fade the new in, to define the parameters for the time at the start and to pause transition on mouse in and out.  I hope others may find it helpful http://jsfiddle.net/Mishutka/p511safe/13/

Answer (score 0):

I know that  setTimeout have trouble with recursivity, if you want to call something regulary you should use setInterval.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp